# C# how do I make a procedure that is run every time a form is loaded?

Tags: c#, forms, methods, fullscreen, windowed

In my c# forms project I want this method to run every time I load any of my forms.

```
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            frm.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        }
```

Comment: Why `foreach` cannot be used in classes and why `WindowState` doesn't exist? I am confused by this.

Comment: is there a mdiParent to your forms ?

Comment: [this is what i see](http://i.imgur.com/elrkz0j.png)

Comment: You write these code in some method of a class. not directly in class

Comment: Please post your full code not an extract, specially when the code you posted is not the problem

Comment: I don't know what more you want honestly. The problem is that i already have this part of code on a button press but it only works for the form its in and isn't permanent.

Comment: I want it to be applied to every form by making this section a method that can be called in the form load of each one but only if the button has been pressed in a previous form to make a condition true. e.g. Button1_toggle() FullscreenMode = true

Comment: You cannot write code in a **class**, you need to create a **method** within that **class** to write code there

Comment: THANK YOU. I completely forgot that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposition: 
Create a BaseClass

```
public class BaseClass: Form
```

... and add method to it:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        frm.Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
    }
}
```

Add this exact base class to each of your forms, like such:

```
public partial class Form1 : BaseClass
```

Comment: Please at least format your code properly

Comment: yes I understand how to make it load for each form but how would I make this only work if a previous condition is true

Comment: Oh I see now.  But here in this method you can use     if(WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)

Comment: and if you really need to know if the button was pressed (windowState is not important, only the fact of clicking button) then I think you need to set some kind of global variable that informs you button was clicked. But this is rather strange solution.

Comment: yeah thats what i want to do but i also want to avoid global variables. I think the reason people didnt understand me was because i barely understood my own problem :/